# WordPress CRON Job at midnight every day

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I'm getting trouble while executing the WP CRON job at midnight every day. When this cron executes, customers notify via email about their expired products.

```
// Make sure event is not already scheduled
if (!wp_next_scheduled('cron_event')) {

        $ve = get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) > 0 ? '-' : '+';

        // Schedule daily expired products event
        wp_schedule_event( strtotime( '00:00 tomorrow ' . $ve . get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) . ' HOURS' ), 'daily', 'cron_event');
}
```

**Server CRON Job Command:**

0 0 * * *   wget -O /dev/null -q http://mywebsite.com/wp-cron.php

This CRON is not executing at midnight but the code works with other timing like when I run it after every two minutes then it is working fine. Is there any issue with server command?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the [Wordpress Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-into-the-system-task-scheduler/) they use `0 0 * * * wget http://YOUR_SITE_URL/wp-cron.php`

Perhaps the `-O /dev/null -q` causes the trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your response. "-O /dev/null -q" is not generated CRON files on the server. I've executed it same for 2minutes everything is working fine. No, issue with this part.

Comment: Also, define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', TRUE ); is added in wp-config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

WP-Cron does not run constantly as the system cron does; it is only triggered on page load.
For two minutes it seems working on time, since you would be loading page too.
Here is the link for the reference.
[https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/#:~:text=WP%2DCron%20does%20not%20run,loads%20occur%20until%205%3A00PM](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/#:%7E:text=WP%2DCron%20does%20not%20run,loads%20occur%20until%205%3A00PM).

Thanks.